# Subsetting data by exluding cases based on number of observations

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Here is the data i have:

```
library(data.table)
ID <- c("A","A","B","C","C","C","C")
Session <-c(1,2,1,1,2,3,4)
Value <- c(10,6,15,20,25,35,35)
Have <- data.table(ID,Session,Value)
Have

    ID Session Value
    A       1    10
    A       2     6
    B       1    15
    C       1    20
    C       2    25
    C       3    35
    C       4    35
```

I would like to subset the data by excluding ID´s that have less than one Session (B in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use an `if` condition after grouping by "ID".

```
Have[, if(.N>1) .SD , by = ID]
#     ID Session Value
#1:  A       1    10
#2:  A       2     6
#3:  C       1    20
#4:  C       2    25
#5:  C       3    35
#6:  C       4    35
```

NOTE: This doesn't take the values in "Session" to consideration.  It is based on the number of rows.

Suppose if the OP mentioned that the number of unique 'Session" should be more than 1, we use `uniqueN` (which is basically `length` of `unique` element)

```
Have[, if(uniqueN(Session) >1) .SD , by = ID]
```

Just to be safe, if the OP wanted to have only 'ID's that have `any` value in 'Session' that are greater than 1.

```
Have[, if(any(Session > 1)) .SD, ID]
```

---

Or if we prefer `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Have %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      filter(n() >1)
```

Comment: I think the best solution for me was the dplyr one. Thanks!